# Combining jQuery UI's blind and slide animation methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Put simply, I want to use both the slide and blind effects in jQuery at the same time on the same element - combining the effect to make it appear as though the element is sliding behind it's containing element (which is what slide does) but also reducing in actual width at the same time so that adjacent elements shuffle along with it.

Before you say 'but there's a plugin for that!', sure there's a few but they all have their own quirks that seem to make them pretty useless for what I want to do.

I've heard I may have to dig into the jQuery code and put these effects together myself as they have a queue method built in by default.. perhaps someone knows better (or where I should start if I want to go down that path?)

Cheers,
John.

Update, have a look yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/johnrobert/xKvF8/

Comment: can you put your code .. on jsfiddle

Comment: Done! I created a simplified version of what I'm doing on there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted...

http://jsfiddle.net/xKvF8/3/

I have used the `dequeue()` here to make them animate at the same time

```
$(".featured:first").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 3000)
    .hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 3000)
    .dequeue();
```

Comment: Spot on!!! This is exactly what I was after. Perfect. Nice bit of code. Thanks very much. If I could give you some extra cred I would.